# r add columns in df1 with count of rows in df2 (conditional)

Tags: r, dataframe, rowsum

I have two data frames in R as below...I need to add new column(count_orders) in df1 which contains count of orders in df2 (or count of buyer in df2).
Please help.

```
> df1
  buyer city
1     A   xx
2     B   yy
3     C   zz
> df2
  order buyer item
1     1     A    1
2     2     A    2
3     3     B    1
4     4     A    2
5     5     B    1
6     6     C    3
7     7     C    4
```

**Expected output:**

```
> df1
  buyer city count_orders
1     A   xx   3
2     B   yy   2
3     C   zz   2
```

Comment: Try: `df1$count_orders<-table(df2$buyer)[as.character(df1$buyer)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a dplyr approach:

```
library(dplyr)
count(df2, buyer) %>% right_join(df1, "buyer")
#Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
#
#  buyer n city
#1     A 3   xx
#2     B 2   yy
#3     C 2   zz
```

You could use `count(df2, buyer) %>% right_join(df1)` and let dplyr figure out the column to join by on its own ("buyer" in this case).

Comment: Thanks for this approach....now I am doing lot other operation on my actual data.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible `data.table` solution that performs a binary join between `df1` and `df2` while calculating length while joining using `by = .EACHI`

```
library(data.table)  
setkey(setDT(df2), buyer)  
df2[df1, list(city, count_orders = .N), by = .EACHI]
#    buyer city count_orders
# 1:     A   xx            3
# 2:     B   yy            2
# 3:     C   zz            2
```

Alternative approach (modification of @nicolas comment) could be (which will update `df1` by reference)

```
library(data.table)  
setkey(setDT(df1), buyer)  
df1[setDT(df2)[, .N, keyby = buyer], count_orders := i.N]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
df1$count_orders<-as.vector(table(df2$buyer)[as.character(df1$buyer)])
#  buyer city count_orders
#1     A   xx            3
#2     B   yy            2
#3     C   zz            2
```

Comment: That's a very nice/efficient solution. works well even if some levels aren't present in `df2`

Comment: Tx David, much appreciated!

Comment: Or maybe (not tested)   `setkey(dt1,buyer);dt1[setkey(dt2[,list(count_orders=.N),by=buyer],buyer)]` where `dt1` and `dt2` are the `data.table` version of `df1` and `df2`.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I guess you could post your comment as answer to show a `data.table` solution and an `.EACHI` usage, which may be helpful in general.

Comment: Ok, btw, the problem with your solution is that it will return a vector, if only one group within `df1` matched to `df2`, while `data.table` simply doesn't have a `drop` argument

Comment: Ok, I've added a modified version of your suggestion while adding `:= i.N` and now it works correctly.